# how can I connect the string as html in python?

Tags: python, html, django

what I try to do is to connect the string like :
but the html can't recognize the valuable forloop.counter0 and displayed messy code

```
<img class="img-polaroid" src= "{% static 'pictures/picture{{forloop.counter0}}.jpg'%}"  alt="店铺名称" />
```

the following is the codes :

```
{% for shop in shops %}
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-3 shop">
  <p > pictures/picture{{forloop.counter0}}.jpeg</p>
  <div class="thumbnails shop_icon">

  <img class="img-polaroid" src= "{% static 'pictures/picture{{forloop.counter0}}.jpg'%}"  alt="店铺名称" />
  </div>
  <div class="shop_desc">
    <h4><a href='/shop/{{shop.id}}'>{{shop.name}}</a></h4>
    <p>{{shop.shoptype}}</p>
    <p>miniprice: {{shop.miniprice}} 元</p>
    <p>amount: {{0}}</p>
  </div>
</div><!-- one shop -->
```

Comment: Maybe `shop` should be able to generate the picture URL?

Comment: I've considered , but it will be easier if the String can be worked...

Comment: I think you should make a custom template tag for this, django's simple tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) could be used.